# Python_assigning variable using Random function

Tags: python

I am new to python with no prior coding experience. I am using "Python Programming for the absolute beginner" by Mike Dawson to learn this language. One of the assignment is - to simulate a fortune cookie and the program should display one of the five unique fortune at random, each time it's run.

I have written the below code, but unable to successfully run the program -

```
# Fortune Cookie
# Demonstrates random message generation

import random


print("\t\tFortune Cookie")
print("\t\tWelcome user!")

# fortune messages
m1 = "The earth is a school learn in it."

m2 = "Be calm when confronting an emergency crisis."

m3 = "You never hesitate to tackle the most difficult problems."

m4 = "Hard words break no bones, fine words butter no parsnips."

m5 = "Make all you can, save all you can, give all you can."

message = random.randrange(m1, m5)

print("Your today's fortune  " , message )

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

Comment: Why can't you run the program? Are you getting an error, won't it start or does it start but doesn't do anything?

Comment: Likely misuse of `randrange`.  user6576756 was expecting it to work by magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in `message = random.randrange(m1, m5)`. The method only takes integers as parameters. You should try putting your sentences in a list instead and test the following:

```
import random

print("\t\tFortune Cookie")
print("\t\tWelcome user!")

messages = [
    "The earth is a school learn in it.",
    "Be calm when confronting an emergency crisis.",
    "You never hesitate to tackle the most difficult problems.",
    "Hard words break no bones, fine words butter no parsnips.",
    "Make all you can, save all you can, give all you can."
    ]

print("Your today's fortune ", random.choice(messages))

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

`random.choice` will take a random element from the list. You could also generate a random number and call by index, but that's not as clear:

```
index = random.randint(0, len(messages) - 1)
print("Your today's fortune ", messages[index])
```

Comment: is the line-by-line formatting for looks? It would be more effective for a beginner to learn the regular version, in my opinion.

Comment: @bjskistad Yeah, it's for looks. It doesn't look as clear when a line is stretching over hundreds of characters so I went with this. Is it really that much harder to understand though?

Comment: Thanks Ted. One quick question - If one has to list down (for example) 1000 items, and generate it randomly, won't this process of listing down each item within the body of the code be cumbersome? What would be an effective process? Thank You for taking the time to review my code and provide your response.

Comment: @ted No, it isn't that hard to understand, it's simply opinions. :)

Comment: @user6576756 the way that Ted provided is actually simpler than making a new variable each time.

Comment: @user6576756 I'm not quite sure I understand. Do you mean it would be cumbersome to write down for example 1000 sentences?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman - sorry if I didn't phrase my question properly. If i have 1K fortune messages which i will like to generate in the same example, would putting the whole 1K in Message = (  ) be cumbersome?

Comment: @Kyo In that case I would put it in an external textfile and read from it instead. 1K lines of stuff that isn't code in a script is quite cumbersome ;P In this case it was such small amount in such a small script that creating an external textfile might be overkill

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Thank You again ted for taking the time. I am new to coding world, hence the newbie questions :D.

Comment: @bjskistad Thanks for the input as well.

Comment: @Kyo sure thing! Glad to help!